# Android Bluetooth tethering, speed capped to 700 kbps?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, bluetooth, android, tethering

I'm trying to use my Android HTC One for [Bluetooth tethering](http://lifehacker.com/5967128/tether-your-phone-over-bluetooth-for-less-battery-drain) (via Bluetooth PAN), so I can access internet on my Windows tablet (Dell Venue 8 Pro).

It works but I can't get any speed higher than 0.7 Mbit/s.
Yeah, Wi-fi/USB tether works fine and I get way better speed, but I want to use Bluetooth over Wifi due to it's consuming less power and can be initiated from outside of the phone. Plugging USB cables also can be a hassle.

My setups are as follows:

---

**Internet <--3G/Wifi--> Android (HTC One) <--BT Tether--> Windows 8.1 PC (Dell Venue 8 Pro)**

---

Both HTC One and Dell Venue Pro 8 have Bluetooth v4.0, so I don't think the hardware involved being a limiting factor here, under Windows network status I can see 3 Mbit/s link

[image: Windows Network Status]

When tested with Speedtest.net APP on my HTC One I can get the full speed as usual

[image]

But when my DVP8 is tethered to my HTC one via BT this is what I'm getting:
[image]

The 0.7mbps speed is consistent, I repeated the speed test several times. Which leads me to believe the BT throughput is capped for some reason.

I also have tested this on my Win8 Desktop PC and I'm getting exactly the same result. USB/WLAN tether gives me higher throughput, close to the speedtest app result.

According to Wikipedia the theoretical transfer speed limit for Bluetooth 4.0 is indeed 3Mbit/s, So I'm expecting 1-1.5mbit/s speed here. (It's the typical 3G bandwidth I can get on my area anyway).

Any thoughts? How can I get speed higher than 700kbps?

Any kind of experience or possible fix are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit, The speed cap happened because the phone was connected to a Wi-Fi AP (effectively acting as Wifi repeater, but via BT). Perhaps something to do with the Wi-fi and BT uses same radio module, thus the speed limitation.

I can get decent throughput when tethering using 3G.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Well, referring to my answer above: Do not use Wi-fi to get connected to the internet. 3G/4G connection works just fine.